# Changing the show of an entry box numerous times

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I would like the contents of this my entry box to be uncovered from the * when the button is clicked, but then recovered when it is clicked again, and so on. Any ideas?

The code i have currently:

```
 password_entry = Entry(root, width = 45, textvariable=user_password, show = "*")

 def Show():
        password_entry.config(show="")

show_password = Button(canvas, width = 31, height = 17, image = eye_img, bg = "gray33", relief = "flat", command = Show)
```

This only uncovers the password, and does not recover it when the button is reclicked.

Comment: Just get the current value of the `show` parameter, and toss in an `if` statement. Are you familiar with how to get the value of an option? It's documented in many places.

Comment: No which is why I asked the question. If i knew that is what i had to do i would not have asked the question. I also do not see why my post was -1'd, I included a valid question with a minimal complete and verifiable example. I really am starting to get confused with how to actually structure my questions cos everything i write is apparently wrong

Comment: The post may have been -1'd because you didn't do any research before asking (or did research but didn't show it). The problem I see with this question is that it's not asking anything that can't be answered simply by reading some documentation.

Comment: I have dived into multiple pieces of documentation. I use this as a last resort. I struggle to understand the language inside the documentatioon, hence why i often have to resort to here. However just -1'ing someones post when they have given all the correct information is a little harsh. You shouldn't be guessing whether or not i have done research.

Comment: It's not whether we're guessing that you did any research or not. The downvote is on the quality of the question, not on you personally. If you did a thousand hours of research but didn't share any of that in the question, the question has the same quality as if you did no research whatsoever. It's really just as simple as that. The vote is for whether the _question_ is of sufficient quality, not whether _you_ are worthy of asking it. In this case, the quality of the question is low according to community standards.

Comment: I just struggle to see the difference between my posts and other posts (which get loads of +1s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems that you are trying to make a toggle button. Edit your function. Get the value of current `show`. If it is `*` then change it to , if it is  then change it to `*`. Your function can be:

```
def Show():
    password_entry["show"] = "*" if password_entry["show"] == "" else ""
```

Here is a sample code that works like expected:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
password_entry = Entry(root, width = 45, show = "*")
password_entry.grid(row=0,column=0)

def Show():
    password_entry["show"] = "*" if password_entry["show"] == "" else ""

show_password = Button(root,text="Show Password",bg = "gray33", relief = "flat", command = Show)
show_password.grid(row=0,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```